# Android actionbar title - change background color

Tags: android

In my Android toolbar on the top I'm using gradient colors on the background. It works just fine, but I noticed the title is wrapped inside something that inherits another one of the gradient colors. How can I change the background of the title into transparent?

```
<style name="Toolbar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/toolbar_gradient</item>
</style>
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/Toolbar"/>
```

> [..[ x ] ... y ]

So the container x wraps the title and has a background color that stands out from the toolbar y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your custom toolbar with title.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/Toolbar">
<TextView android:id="@+id/footer" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="25sp"
        android:singleLine="true" android:background="#07000000"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:text="rrrrr"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />// set your background as you wish
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Ah, such thinking outside the box! Great job, thanks!